# Store a large set of relational data in a JavaScript Electron Desktop App?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, electron

I am building a Bookmarking app using JavaScript and Electron http://electron.atom.io/ to make it a desktop offline app.

Generally I would be building it online as a web app with a PHP and MySQL backend.  As a self hosted Electron desktop app I do not have the pleasure of a nice relational database that can handle massive loads of data!

Some info about my data that I need to somehow store on the users computer for the Electron app...

Assuming this was a typical MySQL database it would have these tables...

- Bookmark Collection Lists
- Bookmark Tags
- Bookmarks
- website URLs (each URL can have 1 record however a bookmark can have multiple records for the same page as long as they all reference the 1 url record.)
- Bookmark Tags relation table to Bookmarks
- Bookmarks relation table to website URLs

Potential issues due to size of data collection...

- Bookmark Tags table could have anywhere from 1 record up to 5,000 records
- Bookmarks and website URL records could easily pass the 10,000 record mark.

My mockup app so far is currently storing the tags and bookmarks in 2 JSON files.  Based on the number of records I will have though I do not see the JSON file being a practical solution!

So my question is, what are some possibble solutions to store this amount of relational data for an offline JavaScript Electron desktop app?

My research so far has only resulted in a few JavaScript libraries that act like a database using things like IndexedDB but I am not sure if these will work with my large data set?

Also is there anything relational I can use as I have Bookmmarks which can have multiple Tag records and searching?  All articles about using SQLite in Electron have resulted in failure as well as my own attempt at it.

---

**UPDATE**

I finally found a working version of SQLite in Electron using SQLJS https://github.com/kripken/sql.js and this test app shows it working  E:\Software\ElectronWebApps\electron-sqljs-master

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Localstorage to persist data in my Electron apps. I haven't tried it, but [localStorageDB](https://github.com/knadh/localStorageDB) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks  localStorageDB looks interesting

Comment: how works the real time data ? between client and server using server side mysql and client side localstorageDB ...